# How to set XYZ-ColorSpace pixel in BufferedImage?

Tags: java, set, rgb, bufferedimage

```
private BufferedImage outputImg;

for(int y = 0; y < inputImg.getHeight(); ++y)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < inputImg.getWidth(); ++x)
    {
        Color originPixel = new Color(inputImg.getRGB(x, y));
        double X = 0.412453 * originPixel.getRed() + 0.35758 * originPixel.getGreen() + 0.180423 * originPixel.getBlue();
        double Y = 0.212671 * originPixel.getRed() + 0.71516 * originPixel.getGreen() + 0.072169 * originPixel.getBlue();
        double Z = 0.019334 * originPixel.getRed() + 0.119193 * originPixel.getGreen() + 0.950227 * originPixel.getBlue();
        //???
    }
}
```

In color space conversion function I get RGB-pixel and convert it into XYZ-pixel. But how to set this result in `outputImg`?
Among `BufferedImage` methods I see only `setRGB(int r, int g, int b)`

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, I have task: Convert Image from RGB color space to another color space (to XYZ for example). Using formulas

Comment: As far as I know, BufferedImage stores images in RGB. if there was a setXYZ, all it would do is convert back to RGB, then store the RGB.

Comment: Thank you, it may be possible to use a different method for storing images, which can be set color space settings?

Comment: I think I found a way out: I create new Color(ColorSpace cspace, float[] components, float alpha) and Graphics g. And draw pixels like one-point-line

Answer (score 1):

To work with a `BufferedImage` in a different color model than RGB, you typically have to work with the `Raster` or `DataBuffer` directly.

The fastest way to convert from an RGB color space (like sRGB) to an XYZ color space (like CIEXYZ), is to use `ColorConvertOp`. However, I assume that this is an assignment, and your task is to implement this yourself.

It's possible to create an XYZ `BufferedImage` like this:

```
int w = 1024, h = 1024; // or whatever you prefer

ColorSpace xyzCS = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_CIEXYZ);
ComponentColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(xyzCS, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
WritableRaster raster = cm.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h);
BufferedImage xyzImage = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, cm.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
```

You can then modify the samples/pixels through the `WritableRaster`, using `raster.setPixel(x, y, pixelData)` or `raster.setPixels(x, y, w, h, pixelData)` or one of the `raster.setSample(x, y, band, ...)/setSamples(x, y, w, h, band, ...)` methods.

You can also get the `DataBuffer`, using `raster.getDataBuffer()`, or if you really like to, access the backing array directly:

```
// The cast is safe, as long as you used DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE for cm above
DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
byte[] pixels = buffer.getData();
```